# Convert timestamp to correct datetime in local timezone - Django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I get a timestamp from an API. When I transform it with:

```
timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(json.loads(m)["_timestamp"], tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
```

I get the correct time in the console when I print it:

```
2021-11-10 15:22:26+01:00
```

But when I save it to the database with:

```
BedTemperatureHistory.objects.create(TimeStamp=timestamp)
```

The Timestamp looks something like this in the database (one hour less):

```
2021-11-10 14:22:26.000000 +00:00
```

My Timezone Settings look like this:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False
```

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to save the correct timestamp in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable time zone support in your settings.

```
USE_TZ = True
```

**EDIT:**
The timestamp is actually stored correctly in your question. You will note that the two times are actually the same, 15:22+01:00 is the same as 14:22+00:00. [Django stores datetimes in UTC](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#overview), to avoid issues with daylight savings:

> Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not change the way it is saved in the Database. Its still +0 in there

Comment: its actually stored correctly, I edited my answer.